# Taylor-Wiles systems for higher dimensional deformation rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, hecke-algebras

Let $R$ be a deformation ring and $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module.

A strategy for proving the theorems $R=T$ is to associate with $(R,M)$ a Taylor-Wiles system denoted $(R_{Q},M_{Q})$. Here I'm talking about Taylor-Wiles systems as defined in definition 2.1 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602606.pdf).

Theorem 2.3 of [the article I mention above](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602606.pdf) shows that if such a TW system exists then (in particular) the ring $R $ is one-dimensional. But according to Mazur's conjecture, deformation rings in general are not one-dimensional, right?

**So my question is this**

Is there a generalization of TW systems allowing larger dimensional rings?

Of course, references are welcome :)

Comment: The phrase "deformation rings" is pretty overloaded here. "Restricted" global deformation rings, where one imposes conditions like "potentially semistable with fixed HT weights and inertial type" at places over p, are expected to be of dimension $\leq 1$ by some old heuristics with Galois cohomology. These are the kind of rings appearing in the Fujiwara paper you cited. "Unrestricted" global deformation rings are supposed to be of "large" but explicit dimension. See e.g. Emerton's 2014 ICM article for some nice discussion of the latter heuristics.

Comment: Dear @Satan'sMinion, thank you for the comment. I know about this Emerton survey but I must admit that I have never read the part you mention (which I will do right away).

Comment: That’s a very naïve question, and I may be completely missing the point, but don’t you expect your Hecke algebra (in the case of an $R=T$ theorem) to be one-dimensional anyway (since you want the spaces of automorphic forms with fixed level to be finitely generated)?

Comment: Dear @Aphelli, you are allowed to define Hecke algebra as an algebra acting on other "automorphic spaces", for example at non-fixed level. For such algebra, you always hope to have an R=T theorem. In any case, I'm not (in this question) interested in R=T theorems, but rather in Taylor-Wiles systems for their own sake. This is actually a purely commutative algebraic question but in a number-theoretic scope.